# Oracle APEX Tabular form info select list disable

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need a lot of help I have a tabular form in the oracle apex that is as follows, in a column f01_000x, I have a char data with a certain situation, when this situation equals 'XXXX', then I have to disable the input data in two other columns of my system at f04 and f05, I've seen some examples here, but since I'm new to technology, I'd like to know where I can enter the validation code and how do I block data entry when the field you have these values

Answer (score 0):

> In Your Tabular form create read only condition . and give condition when your data is "XXXX" then the select list will disable.